# not able to get data in controller

Tags: javascript, jquery, angularjs

**Hi, I am able to get alert of data in controller. but its alerting twice. and showing $rootScope:inprog error.. please help me out**

```
app.factory('orderhistoryfactory', function( $http){ 
return {
    orderhistorydata:  function orderdata(){
        return $http({ url: 'order-history.json', method: 'GET'}) 
        }
    }
 });

app.controller('orderhistorycontroller', function($scope, orderhistoryfactory){
$scope.orderhistory = [];
   orderhistoryfactory.orderhistorydata().success(function(data){
 $scope.orderhistory = data;
alert(data)

   });
});
```

**but when I am using below hard code its working fine.**

```
app.factory('orderhistoryfactory', function($http) {
  return {
    orderhistorydata: function() {
      return [
      {"orderid": "1","receipt": "121abc","deliveredto": "becca","status": "1","date": "1", },
      {"orderid": "1","receipt": "121abc","deliveredto": "becca","status": "1","date": "1", },
      {"orderid": "1","receipt": "121abc","deliveredto": "becca","status": "1","date": "1", }];
    },
  };
});

app.controller('orderhistorycontroller', function($scope, orderhistoryfactory){
 $scope.orderhistory= orderhistoryfactory.orderhistorydata();
});
```

Comment: Inprog error caused by your `alert` function. I've no idea why. It alerting twice may be because the template where this controller exists render twice. what's your template look like?

Comment: Iqbal.. there is only one template ..

Answer (score 0):

i'm not really sure what is going wrong but you could try this and see if it works.

change your factory service to:

```
app.factory('orderhistoryfactory', function($http) {
    return {
        orderhistorydata: function() {
            return $http({ url: 'order-history.json', method: 'GET'})
                .success(function(data) {
                    return data;
                })
                .error(function(errorMessage) {
                    console.log(errorMessage);
                });
            }
    }
```

and then in your controller change `success` after your factory call to `then`. thats how i always format my factory calls and i never got any duplicated responses.

Hope this helps!